# How can I map a domain name to an IP address and port?

Tags: windows-7, dns, ip, port, hostname

I want to give a domain name to the IP address and port for an application in Windows 7. For example, `test.com` should map to `127.0.0.1:59873`.

Is there anyway that we can do it by using a web server or DNS server?

Comment: You are trying to do something that doesn't make any sense. What's your actual problem? What are you trying to make happen?

Comment: I am using one application which is running on 127.0.0.1:5986.I want use this address in different application but this application doesn't accept ":" in 127.0.0.1:5986.So I want to create an name with the ip and port.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no known/easy way to make an alias for an IP/port pair. The closest you can come is making an alias for an IP address with the `HOSTS` file. `:-(`

Comment: Use `127.0.0.2:5986` if you can't specify a port.

Comment: @Synetech Bad troll is bad. Reverse proxies do this all the time.

Comment: @ta.speot.is, fine; drop the “known” from my comment and leave the “easy”.

Comment: Is service on 59873 port http in common?

Comment: Sounds like to me you need an SRV record.

Answer (score 5):

Most webservers can be run as reverse proxies, suitable for doing this. If you do everything right, you'll end up with something like the below (minus the "remote" part - since this will all be on one machine):

[image: reverse proxy]

- **Navigator** is your machine
- **Reverse Proxy** is nginx running on your machine (`127.0.0.1:80`)
- **Remote Server** is the web site running on your machine (`127.0.0.1:59873`)

You can use a lightweight webserver like [nginx](http://www.kevinworthington.com/nginx-for-windows/) (even runs on Windows), [configure it to reverse proxy](http://tumblr.intranation.com/post/766288369/using-nginx-reverse-proxy) `test.com` to `127.0.0.1:59873` and then add the following entry to your `HOSTS` file:

```
127.0.0.1 test.com
```

Comment: looks impressive. Out of interest, why is that called reverse proxy?  a proxy is a middle man.. what is the reverse aspect?

Comment: @barlop what we used to call just "proxy" or proxy server normally sits close to the client, or in the client infrastracture and it is just used by a set of clients to access multiple content. A reverse proxy works close to the server, any client that want to access that content will reach first the reverse proxy.

Comment: Can't this be achieved by making an entry in `HOSTS` file as `127.0.0.1:59873 test.com`. Why need reverse proxy ?

Comment: @SimpleGuy The `HOSTS` file deals with ... hosts. Not ports.

Answer (score 1):

I'm posting this for anybody that is looking to set up a reverse proxy using IIS 7 and above.

For example, in my case, I was trying to use Azure Storage Emulator which is 127.0.0.1:10000 and Remote module of ImageProcessor.Web which does not allow ":" in the whitelisted URLs. So I set a reverse proxy for dev.azureblob.com forwarding to 127.0.0.1:10000.

Nicked from here, done and tested: http://www.myconnectionserver.com/support/tutorials/v90/iisProxy/index.html

> 1. Make sure the following packages have been installed on the IIS server:
>
>    • Application Request Routing
>      • URL Rewrite
> 2. Select the website required from the sites list in IIS. This will display a list of options in the right-hand window.
>
>    Double-click the *URL Write* option.
> 3. Click the *Add Rule* link in the right-hand side menu.
> 4. In the following window select the *Reverse Proxy* option and click the *OK* button.
> 5. Before entering a server name of IP address make sure you check the *Outbound Rules* checkbox.
> 6. Enter the server name or IP address where the HTTP requests will be forwarded.
>
>    You will see that the from field in the *Outbound rules* section will mimic the server name/IP that has just been entered.
>
>    All that is left to do is fill out the *To* section in *Outbound rules*. This is simple as the dropdown list provided will contain the
>      original server name/IP. Simply select it and click the *OK* button to
>      save the changes.
> 7. Process complete.
>
>    There should now be an inbound and outbound URL rewrite rule showing in the *URL Rewrite* window. With these rules in place the
>      website of choice should now work as a reverse proxy.

Comment: One small niggle is that you didn't block quote the text quoted from the link. I've fixed that for you. For future reference please read [How to reference material written by others](http://superuser.com/help/referencing)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a tool like [socat](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/) (there are [versions for MS-Windows](http://blog.gentilkiwi.com/programmes/socat) but I haven't tried them) to create a reverse proxy / port forwarder. The command would be:

```
socat TCP-LISTEN:80,fork TCP:127.0.0.1:59873
```

This is likely to be easier than installing and configuring a full-blown web-server to do the same job.

So if you map test.com to 127.0.0.1 in `%WINDIR%/System32/drivers/etc/hosts` (or similar) you can then access http://test.com/ to reach your application listening on port 59873.