# Can a router map a URL to a local ip?

Tags: networking, router, url, hosts

I'm setting up a facility with many different computers where I don't have access to their hosts files. How would I map test.com to a local server without using the hosts file? Can this be done using a simple home router?

I'd like to be able to tell guests: "If you're on our wifi, you can just go to test.com to view our local website."

I'd prefer to keep answers hardware-agnostic, but if it helps, I'm using a D-link DIR-655.

I'm aware of this answer, but I don't think it addresses these issues directly:
[How can I map a domain name to an IP address and port?](https://superuser.com/questions/394078/how-can-i-map-a-domain-name-to-an-ip-address-and-port)
(Am I mistaken?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I haven't found a home router that can run this without using some custom firmware. However, I use the same server running the sites to host a DNS server internally at home. All the machines point to the DNS server where I have a set of custom directs set up, and all other queries are sent to my ISP's DNS server to resolve correctly. I use DHCP to assign IP's and DNS server addresses to all the clients.

Comment: Thanks -- that confirms my findings. Is this particularly difficult to set up? (I'm running Ubuntu server)

Comment: There are a bunch of lightweight, simple DNS server softwares out in the world.  So, setting up a DNS server can be hard or it can be easy.

Comment: @lrog If your using Ubuntu Server then look at [DNSMasq](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Dnsmasq). It's a DHCP/DNS server roled into one and I have used it successfully in the past, however spent a lot of time searching for the correct config.

Answer (score 4):

I would just register the domain for real and point it to a local IP address. For example, if you registered `example.com` and your local IP address range was `192.168.1.0/24`, you could point `www.example.com` to `192.168.1.184` and run your web server on that IP address. While the name would resolve outside of your network, it wouldn't actually go anywhere.

If you don't want to register a domain for real, instead you can just use your own name servers that make that name resolve however you want. However, I don't recommend this because it could conflict with a real domain.

If you really want to do it by router, use a router than can support [Dnsmasq](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/doc.html). Any router that can support [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/DNSMasq_as_DHCP_server) will do.