# Map local port to public url address

Tags: port-forwarding, port, url

There is two applications Server/Client I use it locally by configure the client app to access the IP and port of the server App. and get some info.
Is there anyway to access the Server App. through public url like `www.mydomain.com/service` ?

Comment: I feel like you should better explain your situation and goal. Your solution may be to register a domain and point it to the server's public ip address or add a hosts file entry on your client.

Comment: Instead of configure Client app to 192.168.1.1 and port 6666 from example I need to replace the local IP and port by URL Address, in this way I can run that client app. outside not only inside local network. I hope it's clear

Comment: I found this [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1048096/751975) but I didn't know how exactly to use socat, I'm not sure if it's solve my problem

Comment: *I need to replace the local IP and port by URL Address, in this way I can run that client app. outside not only inside local network.* There are many more things involved than just the name to achieve this. And if your applications are open to the Internet, they are better be seriously scrutinized for security flaws.

Answer (score 0):

Your comments is very useful in clarifying what you would like to accomplish. You have a local server on your private network and you would like it to be accessible from the Internet.

The right way to do it would be to either:

a) setup your own datacenter with dedicated connectivity, UPS, redundancy, etc.
b) rent a server or vps in someone else's datacenter.

Then, you would register a domain and point it to your server's ip address.

On the other hand, if you just want to expose your home server (for personal use or for tests), you need:

1. a publicly reachable ip address
2. setup port forwarding on your router
3. a domain name to point to your ip address

In case your ip is dynamic (changes over time), you would need to rely on a dynamic dns service.